# List the row of dataframe/attributes in combobox

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, combo-box

I am new to QGIS plugin creation. I have created a 3 Combobox like these `Combobox`, `Combobox_1`, `Combobox_2`. I get the data input from `Combobox` using the lines

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()
self.dlg.comboBox.addItems([layer.name() for layer in layers])
```

[image]

[image]

I stuck here itself. Now I need to select the listed layer from `Combobox`. Then to list the index of the dataframe in `Combobox_1`, `Combobox_2` which from the `Combobox`.

For example, I get the input as per above image through `Combobox` then I need to list like these in `Combobox_1`, `Combobox_2`:

```
 Well_no
 Latitude
 Longitude
 Years
 EC_GEN
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use **QgsMapLayerComboBox** and **QgsFieldComboBox** objects instead. It is easier. For these reason, I think you only need two Combo Box (not three).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Qt Designer, add a `QgsMapLayerComboBox` for "Input file", add `QgsFieldComboBox` for "Latitude" and "Longitude" as in the image.

[image]

In `run` method of your plugin (I guess it has a `run` method), add the following lines. (Use your own object names. I used `cb_input_file`, `cb_latitude`, `cb_longitude`)

```
def run(self):

    # other lines     

    ################### ADD THESE LINES #####################
    def layer_changed(layer):
        self.dlg.cb_latitude.setLayer(layer)
        self.dlg.cb_longitude.setLayer(layer)
        
    self.dlg.cb_input_file.layerChanged.connect(layer_changed)
    #########################################################

    self.dlg.show()

    # other lines
```

Comment: self.dlg.FeildComboBox.setLayer(layer)
AttributeError: 'DegreesminutessecondstodecimaldegreesDialog' object has no attribute 'FeildComboBox'                  how to solve this error.

Comment: @Jo's Check combobox name. Is it `FeildComboBox` or `FieldComboBox` (`Feild`/`Field`)?

Comment: Please add the line you get the error.

Comment: sry its my mistake. I have dout, the list are listed in combobox  is object or not (and why showing like ex: abc Well_No)

Comment: @Jo's You should add CSV using `Layer menu > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer`, not drag-and-drop. [How to do](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html). Otherwise, all columns in CSV added as string. `abc` means that the column is a string.

Comment: Or when you need to use latitude and longitude in your code, convert them to float using ex: `lat = float(feature[FieldComboBox.currentField()])`